# git: working with 'parent' and 'child' repositories

Tags: git, git-submodules, subtree

In my project I want to manage 3 repositories:
PARENT
CHILD1
CHILD2

The reason I'm not using **only one** PARENT repository that contains CHILD1+CHILD2 is that CHILD1\2 can be used in other projects also.

In a specific stage I want to tag all 3 repositories with the same tag.

The goal: In the future, I want to create local repositories from this tag.

During development, CHILD1 (for example) is modified. I want to push the modifications to the remote git.

If someone else is working on CHILD2 (for example) I want to pull last version into my project.

Should I use submodule or subtree or none ?
What is the right way (elegant + simple) to do it ?

Thank you in advance,
Zvika